# Why is the World of Warcraft installation download so slow?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I was wondering if anyone else out there is having problems with the WoW installer, I recently signed up for an account so I could take advantage of this play the first 20 levels for free promotion.

I've registered fine but I now have the downloader client up and it just doesn't seem to want to download the files (and when it does we are talking speeds between 5-15kb/s). I've got a decent 10MB connection from Virgin media and all other net related activity flies by so i very much doubt its that; I've also DMZ'd myself on my router to help with any connection problems that might be occurring. Finally i've also tried adding the TCP and UDP exceptions to my firewall to allow the downloader through Windows firewall.

Does anyone have any ideas as i'm completely stumped?

Comment: My guildies on Virgin Media weren't very positive about network performance in-game either. You might get quite some lag and/or drops.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about general network issues, and unrelated to gaming.

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried disabling peer to peer download? By default, the blizzard downloader use p2p to accelerate the download, but your ISP may be throttling p2p transfer. To disable it, in the blizzard downloader, go to the View --> Preference menu and uncheck the box "Enable peer to peer".

source: http://us.blizzard.com/support/article.xml?locale=en_US&articleId=21065

Comment: I tried this last night and it didn't help unfortunately. Looks like its time to go over the Blizzard support docs again.

Comment: As an alternate source of getting the game client, you could try: [http://www.wowwiki.com/Patch_mirrors](http://www.wowwiki.com/Patch_mirrors). PLEASE NOTE: There is no way to guarantee that these files have not been modified in any way, however they community is normally very good at keeping this list up-to-date and safe.

Answer (score 5):

The Blizzard downloader is a BitTorrent client; unfortunately, Virgin Media appear to block BitTorrent traffic. If switching Peer-to-Peer Download off doesn't work, you can try downloading from an external mirror; [Blizzard have a list of sites likely to host the game files here](http://us.blizzard.com/support/article.xml?locale=en_US&articleId=21079). You'll probably also need to do this every time a new patch is released.

Comment: You could also look at wowwiki or wowpedia for patch mirrors.  There are full install mirror links lower on those pages.

Answer (score 1):

I've have sometimes had this problem before where the download just stops or is just crawling. My best solution is to restart the client. Otherwise try looking at Blizzards troubleshooting forums http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/874936/

Comment: I should have really said this has been an ongoing problem for 3/4 days now so restarting isn't really helping

Comment: Ok then all I can suggest is looking at the forum I linked and maybe re-downloading the client completely?

Answer (score 0):

What does the download report as a warning/error? If there is something it would report it to you.

Try to look for an alternative way to get the download; if not, get a friend to get you the cached files.

Comment: No warnings or errors. Is it possible for a file to just put the files on a couple of dvds and for me to install it from there?

Comment: @Craig: Possible/plausible, use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see where it downloads to.

Comment: The WoW Client is a stand-alone program. You can literally copy the install folder to an external HDD and run it on another computer without issue.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not work for everyone but it worked for me so it might help you if your wow launcher isn't downloading the patch or if it's extremely slow to download it (like 1k every 5 mins)

Also note that this is with Windows 7 Premium

- Open Internet Explorer
- click Tools
- Internet options
- click the Connections tab
- Click Lan settings
- Uncheck the ''Automatically detect settings''
- click ok
- click ok again then close Internet Explorer and try to open the wow launcher again

after that my download was going at 1.6 - 1.8 Mb/sec :)

Also remember to go check the ''Automatically detect settings'' box again after your done, apparently it might cause problem later with your internet if you leave it unchecked (that 's what someone told me)

Hope it help ;)

Comment: Changing your IE settings would not effect the World of Warcraft download.  World of Warcraft use bittorrent traffic by default.

Comment: Ramhound is right. This has nothing to do with browser settings.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, you're mistaken. The Battle.net app and the WoW launcher that used to exist before it both read these particular IE settings and change their behavior based on them. This is easy to see if you are running the app in a debugger, or in Wine (as I do).

Comment: @MichaelHampton - I disagree.  If you are using Wine then it couldn't be using IE.

Comment: @Ramhound Your disagreement is irrelevant. Sorry. In Wine, it uses the _simulated_ settings, or in some cases stubs, as Wine doesn't implement all of this. Your logs, in fact, will be spammed with `fixme:winhttp:get_system_proxy_autoconfig_url no support on this platform` when running Battle.net app in Wine. Oops...

Answer (score 0):

Go into "Options" and select "Patch & Update Settings" and scroll down to hidden fields. Select 0 kb/s for both up and down stream which means unlimited transfer rates. The default setting for background and beta streaming is 100 kb/s. After I did this it jumped to 15+ Mb/S and downloaded in half an hour.